# Redis Session State in Net Core 2.2 deployed at AWS fails

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, redis, iis-8

A little context:

.Net Core 2.2 application Deployed at AWS using IIS

Have implemented REDIS according the aspnet doc [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2] however we get the following exception:

```
    Session cache read exception, Key:65871781-f1f5-71d3-d4e8-a7e031f403eb System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DotNetAgent.Instrumenter.Factories.Web.External.RedisTrackerFactory' from assembly 'DotNetAgent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b69d96e75fbfca'. at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 54 at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 1134 at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisExtensions.HashMemberGet(IDatabase cache, String key, String[] members) at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.GetAndRefresh(String key, Boolean getData) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession.Load() fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession[6]
```

The problem occurs only at Session State cache while regular data has been cached successfully...

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds just like compatibility issue. Have you tried to update .net core wenhosting bundle?

Comment: Yes, we have update to last hosting bundle...

Comment: Seems some obscure package isn't published together with the application. Redis session state works fine at development stage. The problem is to find out which package.

Comment: Since .net core application is run under application pool identity. Would you fix this or get another exception when you set app pool identity to local system or domain user?